# MySQL UNHEX function showing unexpected results in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For all my projects I use a VARBINARY(16) for id fields in the database. The id's are uuid's generated by the following code.

```
function gen_uuid() {
    return sprintf('%04x%04x%04x%04x%04x%04x%04x%04x',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 4
        mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
        // 48 bits for "node"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
    );
}
```

**Windows XP + MySQL 5.5.30 + PhpMyAdmin 3.5.2/3.5.8/4.0.0**

I run the following query in PhpMyAdmin and get an empty result

```
SELECT UNHEX('5578fae02ba342e0bc977266f8e08cf6')
```

If I run it in the MySQL console I get the following result

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| UNHEX('5578fae02ba342e0bc977266f8e08cf6') |
+-------------------------------------------+
| Ux·α+úBα╝ùrf°αî÷                          |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

**FreeBSD + MySQL 5.5.30 + PhpMyAdmin 3.5.2**

I run the same query in PhpMyAdmin and I get the hex version of the ID as the result `5578fae02ba342e0bc977266f8e08cf6`

Running the query in the MySQL console yields the same results as on my XP server

---

**Remarks**
If I browse table data on my XP machine about 10% of the rows do not seem to have an ID. The software and all relations appear to work properly. If I edit the record with the seemingly invalid ID I can see the expected result in the text field on the page. Saving it does not fix anything, changing it to another usually does.

To me it seems to be an issue with PhpMyAdmin but trying different versions has not fixed anything for me so far. I was running mysql 5.5.29 before and updated to 5.5.30 but since the console version seems to work properly I think mysql can be ruled out. Both server run PHP fast-cgi with nginx. Updating to the latest version of PHP did not fix anything.

Other UUID's do work as demonstrated in these screenshots:

---

**XP Server**
[image: XP Server not working]

---

**FreeBSD Server**
[image]

Comment: I find HeidiSQL easier to use the PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Me too, but the database is running on a different PC than I'm working on currently. And I don't think there is a way for me to connect to the server. Thanks for the tip though, HeidiSQL is pretty awesome.

Comment: See the **+Options** link? Expand it to see which they are.

Comment: Played around with them, the show binary as hex option was checked.

Comment: @TFennis - I connect to remote MySQL Servers all the time.

Comment: Yes but I do not have port forwarding on my server :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in PhpMyAdmin, I will report the bug on their forum

```
if ($_SESSION['tmp_user_values']['display_binary_as_hex']
     && PMA_Util::containsNonPrintableAscii($column)
) {
    $column = bin2hex($column);
} else {
    $column = htmlspecialchars(
        PMA_Util::replaceBinaryContents(
            $column
        )
    );
}
```

Removing the `containsNonPrintableAscii` function from the if statement fixes the issue. The reason it was working on our development server turns out to be because the initial patch to add the feature was submitted by my colleague. (And was later destroyed by the PhpMyAdmin dev team)